# Postgres date reporting from log table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Having trouble getting sql to work for a bit of reporting from a postgresql database.  I'm working with two tables, listed below with the relevant columns:

- cohead: cohead_id, cohead_number, cohead_orderdate
- comment:comment_id,comment_source_id, comment_date, comment_text

The two can be joined on cohead_id=comment_source_id to find all comments related to the order.

When we submit an order for picking to our order prep service, we log by inserting a comment with the text "Submitted" for the relevant order.  When we close the order with the order prep service, we insert a comment of "Invoiced" for that order.

What I'd like to do is get a list of each day in a period, say the last month, with a count of the number of orders that had been submitted that day or before, but not yet invoiced as of that day.

I'm having some conceptual problems working this out, and the joins that I have tried are very slow.

Any ideas?

Comment: . . Can you provide some sample data and expected results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken dates `'20130731'`, `'20130805'` as example start and end dates, this query will return you each day between these two dates with count you need. You can change parameters for real query.

```
;with cte as (
    select d::date as d
    from generate_series('20130731', '20130805', interval '1 day') as d
)
select
    cte.d,
    count(o.cohead_id) as cnt
from cte
    left outer join cohead as o on
        o.cohead_orderdate <= cte.d and
        not exists (
            select *
            from comment as c
            where
                c.comment_date <= cte.d and
                c.comment_text = 'Invoiced' and
                c.comment_source_id = o.cohead_id
        )
group by cte.d
order by cte.d
```

see [**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/b7fc3/8) - you can add/remove rows and check if it works ok.

Hope that helps.

**UPDATE**:
If you want to get submitted date instead of order date, you don't have to query orders table at all:

```
;with cte as (
    select d::date as d
    from generate_series('20130731', '20130805', interval '1 day') as d
), cte2 as (
    select
        c1.comment_date as submitted_date,
        c2.comment_date as invoiced_date,
        count(*) as cnt
    from comment as c1
        left outer join comment as c2 on
           c2.comment_source_id = c1.comment_source_id and
           c2.comment_text = 'Invoiced'
    where c1.comment_text = 'Submitted'
    group by c1.comment_date, c2.comment_date
)
select c1.d, sum(c2.cnt) 
from cte as c1
   left outer join cte2 as c2 on
       c2.submitted_date <= c1.d and
       (c2.invoiced_date is null or c2.invoiced_date > c1.d)
group by c1.d
order by c1.d
```

see [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/e924c/6) with updated query

**UPDATE 2** since OP said he has problem with performance of the query, I've tried to write another one with windowed functions. The idea is to get for all dates count of comments with type submitted minus comments of type invoiced and then get the rolling total.

```
;with cte1 as (
    select d::date as d
    from generate_series('20130731', '20130805', interval '1 day') as d
), cte2 as (
    select
        greatest('20130731', c.comment_date) as comment_date,
        c.comment_text, count(*) as cnt
    from comment as c
    where
        c.comment_text in ('Invoiced', 'Submitted') and
        c.comment_date <= '20130805'
    group by greatest('20130731', c.comment_date), c.comment_text
), cte3 as (
    select
        coalesce(cs.cnt, 0) - coalesce(ci.cnt, 0) as cnt,
        coalesce(cs.comment_date, ci.comment_date) as comment_date
    from (select * from cte2 where comment_text = 'Submitted') as cs
        full outer join (select * from cte2 where comment_text = 'Invoiced') as ci on
            cs.comment_date = ci.comment_date
)
select c1.d, sum(c3.cnt) over (order by c1.d)
from cte1 as c1
    left outer join cte3 as c3 on c3.comment_date = c1.d
order by c1.d
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/e924c/19)

Comment: Got me on the right track.  I needed to add in a query instead of just joining on cohead so I could use the Submitted date rather than the order date (they can be different).  But the logic works.  Still takes a while to run, but since it can be an overnight update, no big deal.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: no prob, added another query, may be i'll help you to eliminate performance problems.

Comment: @Dustin sorry for such a massive updates, but I thought that may be query with windowed functions will perform better than two previous queries :) please see update 2

Comment: No problem!  I'm learning a ton.  And I can try different strategies. The window function is quite fast, but the result is -14 in every row when I run it against my data.  Look at it now.

Comment: Sorry, that was, "I am looking at it now."  Your second option looks to be accurate for me, and just about as fast.  To put some numbers on the performance, 700ms vs 50s between the second and the first code you wrote.  Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Great. Theoretically windowed functions should work faster, but for testing it i have to create test cases and I'm lazy now :) good luck